# How to make EntityListBuilder sortable?

Tags: 8, entities

When defining custom content entities one can use [EntityListBuilder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilder.php/class/EntityListBuilder/8) to build a list of those entities for administrative purpose.

By default such entities are ordered by ID, however it is possible to change ordering by overriding [EntityListBuilder::getEntityIds()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilder.php/function/EntityListBuilder%3A%3AgetEntityIds/8). Nevertheless this is only ordering of the items. But how to make that table sortable (by clicking on column header to sort ascending and descending)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how i sort my entityListBuilder :

i use the method load() :

```
  public function load() {

    $entity_query = \Drupal::service('entity.query')->get('produits_entity');
    $header = $this->buildHeader();

    $entity_query->pager(50);
    $entity_query->tableSort($header);

    $uids = $entity_query->execute();

    return $this->storage->loadMultiple($uids);
  }
```

Then i build my header like this :

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildHeader() {

    $header = array(
        'id' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('N° produit'),
            'field' => 'id',
            'specifier' => 'id',
            'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_LOW),
        ),
        'nom' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Nom'),
            'field' => 'name',
            'specifier' => 'name',
        ),

        'prixHT' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Prix HT'),
            'field' => 'prixHT',
            'specifier' => 'prixHT',
        ),

        'statut' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Actif'),
            'field' => 'actif',
            'specifier' => 'actif',
        ),

    );

    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }
```

you need to add in your buildHeader() 2 param for each field you want sort :

> name of field and specifier

Comment: In the end I decided to build my base list builder around your idea, which is nicer from coder perspective than building views as Berdir suggested. Although I recommend using `getEntityIds()` instead of `load()`.

Comment: Nice, that is _almost_ like a tablesort integration! I agree to use `getEntityIds`, it's a bit less code.

Comment: Btw, there are bugs relating to the handling of the `field` key, just one example: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2935344

Comment: Looks like 'entity.query' service doesn't exist in Drupal 9.1, I've used instead 'entity.query.config' see below example.
    `$entity_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('my_entity_type');`
    `$entity_query = \Drupal::service('entity.query.config')->get($entity_type, 'AND');`

Answer (score 10):

Entity query doesn't have tablesort integration. You'd have to implement the query logic yourself.

For content entities, I would strongly recommend to rely on the views integration instead. List builders are limited in functionality and mostly useful for config entities only.

Comment: How is that accomplished? Do you omit the annotation list_builder, how do you encapsulate a view as config within a custom module and also use *.links.task.yml, *.links.action.yml, *.routing.yml etc to string together the functionality?

Comment: One option is that you use a basic list builder or even the default and then also provide a view as either required or optional config. The advantage of that approach is that you still have a predictable generated route name that you can rely on for local actions and so on.

Comment: Ah, do both! Another option could be to programmatically render the view within the list_builder callback.

Comment: I think that would be more complicated for now good reason. Views has a overwrite-existing-route functionality on purpose, so that you can have a non-views fallback and predictable routes (although an abilty to set a route name in views would be great too). By manually calling it, you'd still have a hardcoded views dependency, it would have to be a block/embed view which has some limitations and your code would break if someone deletes that view

Comment: How does views overwrite-existing-route? Just be declaring a path?

Comment: Yes, if it's the same path then views will automatically re-use the existing route.

Answer (score 1):

For now, **DraggableListBuilder** is only available for config entities, not content entities. Take a look at the documentation for DraggableListBuilder 9.0 [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21DraggableListBuilder.php/class/DraggableListBuilder/9.0.x).
I spent about day trying to make that work until I noticed "config" in the route.

The best workaround I've come up with is to ignore **EntityListBuilder** and use the **ContentEntityForm** API instead. ContentEntityForm allows you to use the native TableDrag widget, which adds sortable handles to the form list. There's a well-documented example [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/tabledrag_example%21src%21Form%21TableDragExampleSimpleForm.php/class/TableDragExampleSimpleForm/8.x-1.x).

These are the key lines of code to add to the usual buildform() function:

```
$form['table-row'][$id]['#attributes']['class'][] = 'draggable';
$form['table-row'][$id]['#weight'] = $row->weight->value;
$form['table-row'][$id]['weight'] = [
  '#type' => 'weight',
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#default_value' => $row->weight->value,
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['table-sort-weight']],
];
```

If this solution is of interest, I can add a working example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sortable [DraggableListBuilder available](https://www.drupal.org/node/2089283) now.

```
use Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\DraggableListBuilder;


/**
 * Provides a listing of user roles.
 */
class RoleListBuilder extends DraggableListBuilder {

  public function getFormID() {
    return 'user_admin_roles_form';
  }

  public function buildHeader() {
    $header['label'] = t('Name');
    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }

  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $row['label'] = $this->getLabel($entity);
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }

}
```

You need to make sure your config entities have a weight and label.
[image]