# How add query to EntityListBuilder

Tags: 8, entities

I want to add a query to filter my entity list table.

```
class CommandesLignesEntityListBuilder extends EntityListBuilder {

  use LinkGeneratorTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildHeader() {
    $header['id'] = $this->t('ID');
    $header['produit'] = $this->t('Produit');
    $header['quantite'] = $this->t('Quantité');
    $header['prixHT'] = $this->t('Prix HT');
    $header['TVA'] = $this->t('TVA');
    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {

    /* @var $entity \Drupal\boutique\Entity\CommandesLignesEntity */
    $row['id'] = $entity->id();
    $row['produit'] =$entity->getProduit();
    $row['quantite'] =$entity->getQTE();
    $row['prixHT'] =$entity->getPrixHT();
    $row['TVA'] =$entity->getTVA();

    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }

}
```

This show me all lines. How can I filter this with a query? For example, how can I get only lines with price greater or equal to 100?

i would like a permanent query for this `EntityListBuilder` sub-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone is looking for the same, this is how i use filter on my entityListBuilder :

I override the method getEntityIds for build my logic :

```
   protected function getEntityIds() {
        $query = $this->getStorage()->getQuery()
            ->sort($this->entityType->getKey('id'))
            ->condition('commandes_id',1,'=');

        if ($this->limit) {
            $query->pager($this->limit);
        }
        return $query->execute();
    }




  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildHeader() {

    $header = array(
        'id' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('N° produit'),
            'class' => array(RESPONSIVE_PRIORITY_LOW),
        ),
        'nom' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Nom'),
        ),

        'quantite' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Quantité'),
        ),

        'prixHT' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('Prix HT'),
        ),

        'tva' => array(
            'data' => $this->t('TVA'),
        ),

    );

    return $header + parent::buildHeader();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {

    /* @var $entity \Drupal\boutique\Entity\CommandesLignesEntity */
    $row['id'] = $entity->id();
    $row['produit'] =$entity->getProduit();
    $row['quantite'] =$entity->getQTE();
    $row['prixHT'] =$entity->getPrixHT();
    $row['TVA'] =$entity->getTVA();

    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }
```

Comment: I +1 this as an alternative, but just to clarify, the load method calls getEntityIds by default, so the query should probably be modified in getEntityIds rather than in load. That way someone might call getEntityIds and get completely different results.

Answer (score 4):

Although not exactly a duplicate of [How to make EntityListBuilder sortable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/192757/42650) it is essentially the same answer as Berdir wrote,

> You'd have to implement the query logic yourself.

For instance, BlockListBuilder overrides [getEntityIds](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!block!src!BlockListBuilder.php/function/BlockListBuilder%3A%3AgetEntityIds/8.2.x) to add a condition on the `theme` key.

However as Berdir also notes,

> For content entities, I would strongly recommend to rely on the views
>   integration instead. List builders are limited in functionality and
>   mostly useful for config entities only.