# Make EntityQuery Block Table sortable

Tags: 8, entities, blocks, paragraphs

I made a custom EntityQuery Block Plugin with a table output and managed to make the headers sortable using this **$header definition**:

```
        $header = [
            'title'      => [
                'data'      => t('title'),
                'field'     => 'title',
                'specifier' => 'title',
            ],
            'mydate'       => [
                'data'      => t('mydate'),
                'field'     => 'field_date_paragraph',
                'specifier' => 'field_date_paragraph',
            ]
        ];
```

Then I added a **tablesort** when retrieving the nodes:

```
    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', 1)
        ->condition('type', 'project')
        ->tableSort($header)
        ->condition('field_exhibition.target_id', \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('node'))
        ->execute();
```

The output looks fine and column headers are clickable - but nothing happens. Actually the **GET parameters** get correctly added to the URL and look something like:

```
?sort=asc&order=mydate
```

I think the problem is date field (field_date_paragraph) which is a paragraph field. Inside the paragraph I have a date field and it is this one which should get ordered. What do I have to add to $header definition to make reference to the date field inside **field_date_paragraph**?

Comment: How does it know what to sort on?

Comment: You should also show us the $header definition

Comment: I added the $header definition. I think the problem is that field_date_paragraph is a paragraph field and inside the paragraph there is the date field which should get ordered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify a filed name inside a paragraph in the header array, like field_date_paragraph.DATE_FIELD_NAME (This behavior is, also supported inside condition method)
And here is the issue about lack of documentation https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1924622

Comment: Ok, so I put `'field' => 'field_date_paragraph.field_date',` in `$header` definition, but without any effect. Should I also change the _specifier_? I tried putting `field_date_paragraph.field_date` and also `field_date`, but Drupal gives an error stating `Invalid specifier 'field_fecha'`.

Comment: try with this 'specifier' => array('field' => 'field_name', 'column' => 'value'), also, there are some methods that should help:                                                        
entityOrderBy
propertyOrderBy
fieldOrderBy

Comment: Putting an array as specifier gives an "Array to string conversion" warning in Drupal and follow up errors. Maybe because I don't know how to apply entityOrderBy.

Comment: Are you sure that you're following the example from the d.org link?   $header = array(
    'title' => array(
      'data' => t('Entity field'),
      'type' => 'field',
      'specifier' => array('field' => 'field_name', 'column' => 'value'),
    ),
  );

Comment: Also, check this similar question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192757/how-to-make-entitylistbuilder-sortable?rq=1

Comment: I tried with `'specifier' => array('field' => 'field_date_paragraph', 'column' => 'field_date'),` and get "Array to string conversion" warning and follow up errors. I tried different column values so, but there should go the date field inside the paragraph field right?